# Form submit Button

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

Header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/cssmodulobooking.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/master.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/ficheros/misc.js"></script


<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
```

This is the header my  **issue is that the calender should be displayed when i click or keep cursor on the Arrival field but it is Not displaying**
Wordpress site:

http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress

In normal html (not wordpress) it is displaying perfectly
this is normal html http://design3web.bugs3.com/wordpress/formulario-reservas.htm

Comment: my issue is that the calender should be displayed when i click or keep cursor on the Arrival field but it is not  displaying Wordpress site

Comment: Sorry for typo error in the question corrected it

Comment: You'll need to include the relevant code in your question - where's the javascript that's supposed to assign datepicker to the arrival input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is checking to see if there's an element with an ID of `booking-form` before attaching the date picker. The form has that ID on your working example but it doesn't on the Wordpress site.